# Explicit homeomorphism between the plane and the plane minus a closed half-line.

Tags: general-topology

Let $r$ be a closed half-line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\delta$ a positive real number. I want to find an explicit homeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2-r$ such that $\phi(X)=X$ for all $X$ such that $d(X,r)\geq\delta.$

I can suppose the half-line is $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x\geq0,y=0\}.$ Moreover, if we put $$B=\{X\in\mathbb{R}^2:d(X,r)<\delta\},$$ we must have $\phi(B)=B-r.$

I don’t know how to write this homeomorphism. I thought I can deform this initial configuration into something other, but I don’t have any other ideas.

Comment: $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x\geq0\}$ is the closed right half plane. Do you mean $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x\geq0 , y =0\}$?

Comment: Yes, I have corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us proceed in various steps.

(1) It clearly suffices to show that for any $a > 0$ there exists a homeomorphism $h_a : \left( [-a,\infty) \times [-a,a] \right) \setminus r \to [-a,\infty) \times [-a,a]$ which is the identity on the boundary $B_a$ of the strip $S_a = [-a,\infty) \times [-a,a]$.

(2) It suffices to consider $a = 1$. Define $g_a : [-1,\infty) \times [-1,1] \to [-a,\infty) \times [-a,a], g_a(x,y) = (ax,ay)$. This is a homeomorphism (its inverse is $g_{1/a}$) such that $g_a(r) = r$ and $g_a(B_1) = B_a$. If we have found $h_1$, then take $h_a = g_a \circ h_1 \circ g_{1/a}$.

(3) Define a map $p: [-1,1] \times [-1,1] \to [-1,1] \times [-1,1]$ as follows. For each $y \in [-1,1]$ let $p_y : [-1,1] \to [-1,1]$ denote the piecewise linear map such that $p_y(-1) = -1$, $p_y(-\lvert y \rvert) = 1 - 2 \lvert y \rvert$, $p_y(1) = 1$. Then define $p(x,y) = (p_y(x),y)$. Explicitly
$$p(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
1 +2 x & -1 \le x \le - \lvert y \rvert \\
1 - 2 \lvert y \rvert + \dfrac{2 \lvert y \rvert}{1 + \lvert y \rvert}(x + \lvert y \rvert) & - \lvert y \rvert \le x \le 1
\end{cases}
$$
It is an easy exercise to verify that $p$ is continuous. Moreover, $p$ is the identity on the boundary $D$ of the square $Q = [-1,1] \times [-1,1]$. It maps $[0,1] \times \{ 0 \}$ to the point $(0,1)$ and restricts to a continuous bijection $p ': Q' \setminus r' \to Q'$, where $Q' = [-1,1) \times [-1,1]$ and $r' = [0,1) \times \{ 0 \}$. Since $Q$ is compact, $p$ is a closed map and therefore a quotient map. Let $U \subset Q' \setminus r'$ be open. Since $Q' \setminus r'$ is open in $Q$, $U$ is open in $Q$. We have $p^{-1}(p(U)) = U$, hence $p(U)$ is open in $Q$. Thus $p'(U) = p(U) = p(U) \cap Q'$ is open in $Q'$ which shows that $p'$ is an open map, i.e. a homeomorphism.

(4) Let us finally construct the homeomorphism $h_1$ as in (2). Define a homeomorphism $\psi : [-1,1) \to [-1,\infty)$ by $\psi(x) = x$ for $x \le 0$ and $\psi(x) = \dfrac{x}{1-x}$ for $x \ge 0$. Then $\psi' = \psi \times id : Q' \to S_1$ is a homeomorphism such that $\psi'(r') = r$. It maps the boundary of $Q'$ onto the boundary of $S_1$ and restricts to a homeomorphism  $\phi: Q' \setminus r' \to S_1 \setminus r$. Now define
$$h_1 = \phi \circ p' \circ \phi^{-1} .$$

Comment: @MatP Any reaction would be nice. If you are not satisfied with an answer, you should tell it to author, and you can also downvote. On the other hand, if the answer is helpful, you should accept it. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. No reaction also leaves the question in the uanswered queue which is confusing for the users. If you click at "Unanswered" in the upper left corne of this page, you will read something like "235,857 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers ". If you look at these questions, you will see that a great many are actually answered.

Answer (score 0):

Using polar coordinates (r,t) where
{ (r,0) : 0 <= r } is the removed closed ray,
map (r,t) to (r,$\pi$ + t/2).

Comment: In polar coordinates $(r,t)$ stands for $re^{it}$ with $t \in (0,2\pi)$. But then $\pi +t/2 \in (\pi,2\pi)$, i.e. the image of your map is the open lower half plane.

Comment: You got it.  Now finish the homeomorphism.

Comment: Yes, but it will be not a homeomorphism as required in the question.